# Best way to reinforce beam for a deadbolt?

Tags: garage, lock, garage-door

I want to install a deadbolt into the garage door but with that one beam of wood I feel someone could easily kick it open?

What's the best way to reinforce it before installing a deadbolt. Or if anyone has better lock suggestions I'd be open to them [image]

Answer (score 2):

I would sister up another 2x4 inside of the existing stud (weird to see a single stud there anyway, usually you would have a stud and a trimmer). Secure it with screws along the entire length.

Use heavy bolts with washers from the opening/door side to the back side of the studs, above and below the strike plate/latch area. To make them sit flush on the opening/door side, countersink the heads.

Then install a heavy duty reinforced strike cup and plate unit, there are many types and sizes available:

[image]

Comment: Then put a sign on your gate that says "24 hour video surveillance and ARMED response".

Comment: Would it be secure with the strike box cup/plate using only a door knob lock or also opt for a deadbolt?

Comment: They make them for regular lock strikes and for deadbolts but an additional deadbolt would add to strength vs. kick-in. Keep in mind that short of a steel door and frame there is no such thing a a kick proof door if the thief is determined. All you can hope for is enough strength to deter the bad guy to look for an easier target. Other supplemental security features (motion lights, gates, signs, cameras, etc.) will help, you want a multi-layered approach.

Comment: Yeah true. It's my first house and I'm all weary about it. Luckily there are motion sensors already installed. Maybe I'll add those alarms that sound when a door is opened. Any recommendations on lock brands? Can't find any grade 1/2 locks at my local hardware stores all I've seen is grade 3. Isn't that the weakest kind?

Comment: Instead of the hardware store, pay a visit to a local reputable locksmith. I always try to find craftsmen who are members of a trade association or guild as it is one indicator of competence and reliability: Associated Locksmiths of America- www.findalocksmith.com/search.aspx

Comment: Thanks for your help man. What size screws should I use for doubling that 2x4? Should I pre-drill pilot holes or not necessary?

Comment: Yes, drill pilot holes to prevent splitting. I would use 2 1/2" multi-purpose screws, and countersink them so the heads sit flush in the door jamb.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation many years ago in an apartment where the door was kicked in.  I cut out a section of the 2x4 jamb and replaced it with hard maple and a piece of bar stock.  That is great for the jamb, but, like others have pointed out, the deadbolt itself and the door are no stronger.